# Cron job runs and stops mysteriously?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, cron

I have a cron set on ubuntu to run some Laravel scheduled commands. It's running sometimes and stopping at random times. last week it did not run the commands for the whole week, the it started to run again yesterday. This morning it stopped again. I have tried everything but nothing seems to be solving the issue. What am i missing?

Here is the cron:

```
*/15 * * * * ubuntu cd  /var/www/html  && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

And Here is my Kernel.php:

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\TrackData::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('data:track')->withoutOverlapping()
            ->everyFifteenMinutes()->appendOutputTo(storage_path().'/logs/laravel_output.log');
        
        $schedule->command('queue:listen')->withoutOverlapping()
         ->everyFifteenMinutes()->appendOutputTo(storage_path().'/logs/laravel_output.log');
         
        $schedule->command('delete:oldxml')->withoutOverlapping()
            ->dailyAt('00:01');

        // $schedule->command('sitemap:generate')
        //                 ->daily();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I've tried everything but nothing seems to solve the problem. What am i missing

Comment: Check PHP error logs

Comment: the scheduler needs to be ran every minute

Comment: In order to know what is going on, replace your `>> /dev/null 2>&1` by `>/tmp/out 2>/tmp/out2`.  This will show you everything that is going on.  As posted, we do not have enough to help much.  Also, `ubuntu cd ...`, what does `ubuntu` do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

it might be many reasons for this kind of problem where your crontab suddenly stopped working.

1. it might be related to crontab user. to solve the problem, you can try to delete all crontabs for both root and other users.
2. You can catch the script error into a log file for better investigation as following.

`*/15 * * * * ubuntu cd  /var/www/html  && php artisan schedule:run >> /tmp/script.log 2>&1`

3. it might be related to the PHP config. Your script may run longer than your php.ini's **max_execution_time** and also check **set_time_limit()**
4. You can check cron log by using this command `tail -fn 100 /var/log/cron`
5. it might occur due to script file permission and ownership of script files. so make sure you give proper permission to the script file.

`chmod +x yourscript.sh  chown root:root yourscript.sh`

6. it might be related to OS. Maybe your webserver disk is full or an OS that can't spawn new threads.
7. Maybe your script has begun to overlap themselves and */15 * * * * is not enough. you can try to increase time to  */30 * * * *

Comment: Thanks a lot figured out that */15 * * * *  was not enough. Everything working fine now. Hope the issue is solved for good now.